# Supporting orientations IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, rotation

Hello i want to support portrait, home button up and down in my application how can i do that?

i go to my project settings check those two [image]

and i add the code below

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation); 
}
```

I also tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

but none seems to work

any help

Comment: Are you sure you put the code in the correct controller?  Have you tried just returning YES to see if maybe it is a problem with your logic (even though it looks ok)?

Comment: Everything is right but... Where did you put that code? On which controller?

Comment: yeah i have a view controller and it's there i tried also YES and that's not working either

Comment: well i have an appDelegate through there i create a view named FirstViewController and there i put my code. The FirstViewController is also in a tabBarController item

Comment: if your app consists of several view controllers inside a UITabBarController you have to put that code into all viewControllers in you tab bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{  
    if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
        return YES;
   }
   return NO;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, you can try this (just for the sake of testing)

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{  
    return YES;
}
```

if this doesn't work, either you are not messing with the right view controller, or the parent/root view controller has rotation disabled (returning NO in shouldAutoRotate method of the rootVC)

Comment: @fbernardo already suggested that and OP said it doesn't work for him.

Comment: Well it worked i had to put that code in every view i had cause that was in a tab bar controller thanks a lot for your help